# Creating a foreign key to compound primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, azure-sql-server

I have two tables - **Educators** and **Faculties**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Educators]
(
    [UserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [FacultyId] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [InstitutionUserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Educators] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Faculties]
(
    [InstitutionUserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [FacultyId] [smallint] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserFaculties] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([InstitutionUserId] ASC, [FacultyId] ASC)
)
```

The table `Faculties` has a compound primary key made up from two columns (`InstitutionUserId` and `FacultyId`). I also have the same column in the `Educators` table. I want to link those two tables together with a foreign key.

So, this is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Educators] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Educators_FacultyId_Faculties_FacultyId] 
    FOREIGN KEY ([FacultyId], [InstitutionUserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Faculties] ([FacultyId], [InstitutionUserId])
```

But I getting this error message:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Faculties' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_Educators_FacultyId_Faculties_FacultyId'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your tables and their constraints look fine. The only issue I can see is that the order of the columns in your primary key

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_UserFaculties] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InstitutionUserId] ASC,
    [FacultyId] ASC
)
```

is different from the order that you've declared in your foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Educators]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Educators_FacultyId_Faculties_FacultyId] FOREIGN KEY([FacultyId], [InstitutionUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Faculties] ([FacultyId], [InstitutionUserId])
```

Try changing the order of the columns in the declaration of your foreign key like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Educators]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Educators_FacultyId_Faculties_FacultyId] FOREIGN KEY([InstitutionUserId], [FacultyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Faculties] ([InstitutionUserId], [FacultyId])
```

Answer (score 1):

The keys should be in the same order that they are defined:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Educators
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Educators_FacultyId_Faculties_FacultyId
        FOREIGN KEY(InstitutionUserId, FacultyId)
            REFERENCES dbo.Faculties(InstitutionUserId, FacultyId);
```